# Writing a set of ODEs in matrix notation

Tags: matrices, ordinary-differential-equations

The system I'm interested in is of the form:

$$dx_i = x_i\left(b_i-\sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij}x_j^2\right) dt$$

For programming purposes, it would be easier to be write this set of ODEs in matrix form. Unfortunately, I've been unable to do that. Without the square, it's easy:

$$dx_i = x_i\left(b_i-\sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij}x_j\right) dt \implies dx = diag\left(x_1,\cdots,x_n\right)\left[b-Ax\right]dt$$

Is there a nice way to extend this to the case with the square?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One immediate variant is
$$dx=diag(x_1,…,x_n)·[b−A·diag(x_1,…,x_n)·x]·dt$$

You might want to apply vectorized operations in python, matlab, ...

```
dx = x .* (b - A *  x.^2) * dt
```

Comment: Thank you! I had been struggling to come up with this for awhile. I usually just use np.diag for python. I got it to work now, so thank you!